Obtencion de metadatos de una propiedad de una clase
Estoy haciendo una API en NestJS
En la cual defini un endpint el cual sirve para hacer login.
  @Post('signin')
  async signin(@Body() authLoginDto: SigninRequest): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }

Este controllador recibe un DTO como parte del body el cual defini de la siguiente manera
export class SigninRequest {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsEmail({}, { message: "INVALID_EMAIL" })
    email: string;

    @ApiProperty({ minLength: 8 })
    @IsEncrypted()
    @IsString({ message: "PASSWORD_MUST_BE_STRING" })
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: "EMPTY_PASSWORD" })
    @IsStrongPassword(
        { minLength: 8, minLowercase: 1, minNumbers: 1, minSymbols: 1, minUppercase: 1 },
        { message: "PASSWORD_TOO_WEAK" }
    )
    password: string;
}

como veran la propiedad password tiene un decorador llamado IsEncrypted
este decorador lo defini de la siguiente manera:
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const IS_ENCRYPTED: string = "is_encrypted";

export const IsEncrypted = (): PropertyDecorator => SetMetadata(IS_ENCRYPTED, true);

yo lo que necesito es antes de procesar la peticion porder transformar el valor de la propiedad password, para esto me cree un Pipe de tipo PipeTransform
@Injectable()
export class DecryptPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private reflector: Reflector, private readonly cryptographyService: CryptographyService) {

  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const keys = Object.keys(value);

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

      const key = keys[i];

      const isEncrypted = ...;
      if (isEncrypted) {
        value[key] = await this.cryptographyService.decrypt(value[key]);
      }
    }

    return value;
  }

}

para poder hacer esto tengo que saber que propiedades tienen el decorador @IsEncrypted()
y acá radica mi problema. se que tengo que hacer uso de Reflection para poder solucionar este problema pero no me doy cuenta como puesto que ya intente haciendo:
const metadata = Reflect.getMetadata(IS_ENCRYPTED, value, key);
pero me devuelve undefined.
Saludos, muchas gracias

Pude resolverlo haciendo uso de un paquete llamado @loopback/metadata
redefini el decorador de la siguiente manera:
import { PropertyDecoratorFactory } from '@loopback/metadata/dist/decorator-factory';

export const IS_ENCRYPTED_KEY = 'isEncrypted';

export function IsEncrypted(): PropertyDecorator {
    return PropertyDecoratorFactory.createDecorator<boolean>(
        IS_ENCRYPTED_KEY,
        true,
    );
}

y el pipe quedo de la siguiente mantera:
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IS_ENCRYPTED_KEY } from 'src/common/decorators/is_encrypted/is_encrypted.decorator';
import { CryptographyService } from 'src/modules/services/cryptography/cryptography.service';
import { MetadataInspector } from '@loopback/metadata/dist/inspector';

@Injectable()
export class DecryptPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private readonly cryptographyService: CryptographyService) {

  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {

    const allProps = MetadataInspector.getAllPropertyMetadata<boolean>(
      IS_ENCRYPTED_KEY,
      metadata.metatype.prototype,
    );

    for (const prop in allProps) {

      var text = value[prop];

      value[prop] = await this.cryptographyService.decrypt(text);
    }

    return value;
  }

}


Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada aunque sea tuya.

aun tengo que esperar 1 hora para que me deje marcarla
